# grep and replace two constitutive strings

Tags: sed, grep

I would like to grep and replace two consecutive strings:

To grep and replace one string is easy :

```
grep -lr -e '00000'  * | xargs sed -i 's/00000/11111/g'
```

but I wanted to grep two strings in a file:

```
 grep -w  'P000\|00000' file_name
```

The above command indeed can grep the two consecutive strings, "P000" and "00000" in the file named "file_name"

Now I want to replace these two consecutive 
strings "P000 0000"  by  "C1000 11111".

How can I do that ?

Comment: `s/P000 0000/C1000 11111/`?

Comment: `"P000 0000" by "C1000 11111".` or `"P000 00000" by "C1000 11111".` ? (5 zeros in later)

Comment: grep -w   "$line1\|$line2"  * | xargs sed -i  "s/$line1 $line2/$line1 $line3/g"  does not work, where $line1 is P000 and $line3 is 11111

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to match two consecutive strings,

```
sed 's/$string1$string2/$newString1$newString2/g'
```

if you need to maintain some number of characters between them:

```
sed 's/$string1\(.*\)$string2/$newString1\1$newString2/g'
```